# How to load JavaScript files using HTTPS (and not HTTP) require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm working with a project that uses require.js to load javascript files and dependencies of it. All of the javascripts was all working fine when we are using HTTP but after we convert to HTTPS it does not load properly and I got an error. I am very new to require.js. Thanks for helping me in advance.

This is the error:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://ourdomainhere.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

loading a javascript file

```
requirejs.config({

  paths: {
    //how can I make this to call https and not http?
    'angular': '../lib/angularjs/angular'    
  }

});
```

My question is how can I make require.js call https and not http for loading javascript files? Does the problem is with require.js or in our SSL cert?

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with full path?

Comment: something like this? https://ourdomain.com/assets/lib/angularjs/angular

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is that you load your angular from HTTP site http://cdn.jsdelivr.net. You have to load https://cdn.jsdelivr.net
You can use and  `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min` instead of googleapis.

```
requirejs.config({

  paths: {
    'angular': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min'    
  }

});
```

Can you try it?

Comment: I already have angularjs files in my library. Is it possible that I targeted that file instead of cdn? or should I use cdn?

Comment: You shouldn't use HTTP cdn. If I were you, I'll use local resources (angularjs files in my library).  HTTPS is also possible instead of local resource.